# Grouped conditional sum in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, conditional-statements

`my_table` shows the account balance of each person's credits *N* months ago. From this table, I want to get the monthly sum of each person's balances for the past 2 and 3 months and divide each sum by 2 and 3 respectively (that is, a moving average of the sum of balance for the last 2 and 3 months).

Please note that I need the sum of the balance in the past *M* months divided by *M* months.

```
PERSON_ID  CRED_ID  MONTHS_BEFORE  BALANCE
       01       01              1     1100
       01       01              2     1500
       01       01              3     2000
       01       02              1       50
       01       02              2      400
       01       02              3      850
       02       06              1      300
       02       06              2      320
       02       11              1     7500
       02       11              2    10000
```

One way to do this would be to:

```sql
select
    person_id, sum(balance) / 2 as ma_2
from
    my_table
where
    months_before <= 2
group by
    person_id
```

and merge this result with

```sql
select
    person_id, sum(balance) / 3 as ma_3
from
    my_table
where
    months_before <= 3
group by
    person_id
```

I want to know if this can be handled with a `case` or a conditional sum or something along these lines:

```sql
select
    person_id,
    sum(balance) over (partition by person_id when months_before <= 2) / 2 as ma_2,
    sum(balance) over (partition by person_id when months_before <= 3) / 3 as ma_3
from
    my_table
```

The desired result would look as follows:

```
PERSON_ID     MA_2     MA_3
       01  1525.00  1966.66
       02  9060.00  9060.00
```

Comment: You mention "months" but I see nothing to that effect in your data.

Comment: Oh, `delay` is the number of months before the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these two queries gives what you want and you need to merge them then only `ma_2` needs conditional sum:

```
select person_id, 
       sum(case when months_before <= 2 then balance end) / 2  as ma_2,
       sum(balance) / 3 as ma_3
  from my_table
  where months_before <= 3
  group by person_id
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f19ad8dba0b09a66f5af82c4f4308ed4)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

If you had a "month" column, you would use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       avg(balance) over (partition by person_id
                          order by month
                          rows between 2 preceding and current row
                         ) as avg_3month
from t;
```

Comment: Will this average give me the sum of all the balances per `person_id` divided by the number of credits or will it give me the sum of all the balances divided by the number of different months?

Comment: @ArturoSbr . . . This gives you a running average per person, which is how I interpret the question.